# Decode LDAP-CRL and get FQDN

Tags: certificate, ldap

I have a certificate with the following CRL:

```
URL=ldap:///CN=GOLF Root-CA,CN=VSCERT02,CN=CDP,CN=Public Key Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=toplevel-domain,DC=de?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint (ldap:///CN=GOLF%20Root-CA,CN=VSCERT02,CN=CDP,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=toplevel-domain,DC=de?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint
```

Because after migrating from VPN to a ZTNA network solution, we have problems with that CRL. Unfortunately I cant find out the FQDN that is on a DNS/network level asked to access it.

How do I get the FQDN from that CRL?

Best regards
Linus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This LDAP **U**RL looks like it was generated by MS AD Certificate Services, pointing to a CRL that's stored in an Active Directory LDAP object.

It's deliberately missing the LDAP server FQDN, as Active Directory does not usually have a fixed FQDN for services (i.e. there's no "ldap.example.com" unless an admin manually creates one), instead AD clients are supposed to make DNS SRV queries to discover all available domain controllers (Windows does this automatically).

To find all DCs in a domain, make an SRV query for the `_ldap._tcp` subdomain:

```
host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.toplevel-domain.de

nslookup -q=SRV _ldap._tcp.toplevel-domain.de
```